# Pulley getting pulled

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics

[image]

I cannot seem to figure out the mistake in my work when attempting to solve this problem.

I have drawn out the force vectors in this image
[image]

Now, based on intuition, I know that the block on top will move faster than the block on the bottom, which will force the pulley to move a bit faster (kinda slipping across the rope) than it would be moving normally (with respect to the heavier block).

Thus I generated this equation:
$a_{n}=a_{m}+a_{2m}$

Now, the acceleration of the lower block can be found by:

$3mg-2mg=2m*a_{2m}$

$\frac{g}{2}=a_{2m}$

We can find the acceleration of the upper block through another set of equations.

$3mg-mg=m*a_{m}$

$2g=a_{m}$

Thus the net acceleration should be equal to:

$a_{n}=\frac{g}{2}+2g=\frac{5g}{2}$

However, this isn't even an answer choice. Can someone provide some sort of hint that can aid me in solving the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some hints:

1. If the pulley is moving with acceleration a, neither block is moving with this acceleration.  If the m block is moving with acceleration $\delta$ relative to the pulley, the 2m block is moving with acceleration -$\delta$ relative to the pulley.  So the m block has absolute acceleration $a+\delta$ and the 2m block has acceleration $a-\delta$.
2. The normal force from table on the 2m block is not 2mg.

Comment: Thanks for the help!